# Change onClick function for a react component in a loop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have made a component for a navigation menu which closes and open when clicked

```
class Panel extends Component {

openNav() {
    // opens the navigation menu
    // changes onClick attribute to closeNav()
}

closeNav() {
    // closes the navigation menu
    // changes onClick attribute to openNav()
}


render () {
    return (
        <div id="panel" className="hamburger" 
        onClick= {/*default value is openNav(),and when clicked, 
        changes to closeNav()*/} ></div>
    );
}
}
```

Is there a way to write openNav() and closeNav() such that they can be called repetitively one after other when clicked? 
Also please tell what to pass to onClick attribute in render().

Comment: why dont you use `toggleNav` which just negates current value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could call your function "toggleNav" and then do something like this:

```
onToggleNav() {
    this.setState({
        isNavbarOpen: !this.state.isNavbarOpen
    });
}

render () {
    return (
        <div
            id="panel"
            className="hamburger" 
            onClick={::this.onToggleNav}
        >
            // I don't know if the div is your navbar or you have a specific navbar component. I just use the component below for demonstration purposes how to use the state then.
            <Navbar
                isOpened={this.state.isNavbarOpen}
            />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Actually div is the navbar. used hamburger to make it.

Comment: Ok so are you able to translate the solution into a solution working for you or not?

Comment: Yep, it works, but can you tell me what '::' means in onClick={::this.onToggleNav} ?

Comment: ::this.onToggleNav is the short version of this.onToggleNav.bind(this)

Answer (score -1):

You can use a state variable `this.state.open` to determine if the menu is opened or closed:

```
class Panel extends Component {

constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  // You need to bind your functions in the constructor
  this.openNav = this.openNav.bind(this);
  this.closeNav = this.closeNav.bind(this);
  this.onClick= this.onClick.bind(this);
}

openNav() {
    this.setState({open: true});
}

closeNav() {
    this.setState({open: false});
}

onClick() {
  if (this.state.open) {
    this.closeNav();
  } else {
    this.openNav();
  }
}

render () {
    return (
        <div id="panel" className="hamburger" 
        onClick= {this.onClick} ></div>
    );
}
}
```

Comment: Well your solution works, but adds a lot of unnecessary and unreadable stuff to the component. And you tremendously extend the components public API which is the most dangerous thing here.

Comment: @Tobias My solution follows the structure that OP has in place. Which part is unreadable and which part is a "public API" here ? Also what is so dangerous about it ?

Comment: It's not about the structure in OP, it's the whole context. Imagine somebody else wants to use your (reusable) component. All functions in JS are public by definition, so your components API looks like: openNav, closeNav, onClick. onClick semantically tells me that it's an internal event handler so I wouldn't call it from outside. "openNav" and "closeNav" are imperativs, so you could imply that these functions are used to be called from outside which should clearly not. That's not how React.js is supposed to work, is it?

Comment: And don't get me wrong. I don't want to cheapen your solution - everybody's happy about each person helping others here on Stackoverflow and so it's me :-) I just want to point out things that are worth to discuss about.

Comment: All methods are public in JS. So every method in every React component will always be public. In a real life app, components will have dozens of different methods... But the way a React app is setup you would never call these methods from outside the component itself. My solution is voluntarily un-optimized (having many methods and duplicated code) so that OP can focus on what really matters here: introducing a state variable to store `open`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161282/discussion-between-tobias-and-klugjo).

Comment: This solution also works and is easier to understand but can you tell me what OP means here?

Comment: @klugjo can you please tell me what OP means here?